# getting a number to round using a loop instead of a class in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to get the square root of a number rounded within .000001 of the number.  For example sqrt of 10 = 3.1622766..... with a double.  I have that but getting rounded down to 3.162267 is the problem I am having. I have to use a loop and cannot use classes.  Thank you Jared

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class squareRoot {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a non-negative integer.");
        int myInt = kb.nextInt();
        {
            double testNum;
            double squareRoot = myInt / 2;
            do {
                testNum = squareRoot;
                squareRoot = (testNum + (myInt / testNum)) / 2;
            }
            while (squareRoot - (testNum * testNum) > .000001);
            System.out.println("\nThe square root of " + myInt + " is " + squareRoot);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, those indentations are *really* confusing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that using this algorithm, there is an element of error on the last digits, so you could increase the number of significant figures, and then round to the desired number:

```
double myDouble = kb.nextDouble();
{
    double testNum;
    double squareRoot = myInt/2;
    do
    {
        testNum=squareRoot;
        squareRoot = (testNum + (myInt/testNum))/2;
    }
    while(Math.abs(myDouble - (testNum * testNum)) > .00000001);//←decrease the error here

    //round squareRoot down to the num of decimals you want        

    System.out.println("\nThe square root of " + myDouble + " is " + squareRoot);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own `round()` method and use it instead of build in java classes:

```
private static double round(double number, int places){
    double result;
    if(number == (int) number){
        return number;
    }
    result = (int) number;
    int multiplier = 1;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < places ; i++){
        multiplier*= 10;
    }
    double fraction = number - (int)number;
    result = result + ((int)(multiplier * fraction))*1.0/multiplier;
    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double d = 1.6546213;
    System.out.println(round(d, 2));
}
```